# Fetching firebase database is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a webpage that allows companies to post jobs and for certain people to apply for this jobs. I have figured out how to allow companies to create Jobs and save it in Firebase DB in the Jobs child below. What is not working now is how to retrieve all the Jobs saved in the Job child and populate my Job board with them. I have made many trials but the Job board is not being populated with database entries. My code and illustration are below for better clarification.

[image]

My code

```
  <article class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="cards"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash icon"></span>
    <hr class="divider"/>
    <h2 class="title" id="jobTitle">Job Title</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <hr class="divider"/>
      <p class="lead" id="jobDescription"><Strong>This is where Job description goes</strong></p><a class="btn btn-lg center-block" onclick="location.href = 'Specialistscard.html';">Specialists</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

function createJobElement() {
   var jobRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Jobs')
   var jobTitle = document.getElementById('jobTitle');
   var jobDescription= document.getElementById('jobDescription');

   firebase.database().ref('Jobs/' + key).on('value',   function(snapshot){

      jobTitle.innerHTML = snapshot.val().JobTitle;

      jobDescription.innerHTML = snapshot.val().JobSummary;

    });
}

function startDatabaseQueries() {
  var recentJobs = firebase.database().ref('Jobs/' + key).orderByKey();
  var jobRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Jobs');
  var fetchJobs = function(jobRef, sectionElement) {
    jobRef.on('child_added', function(data){
      var containerElement = sectionElement.getElementsByClassName('col-xs-4')[0];
      containerElement.insertBefore(createJobElement(data.key, data.val().JobTitle, data.val().JobDescription), containerElement.firstChild);      
    })
  }
  fetchJobs(recentJobs);
 }
```

I was trying to order the Job entry by key and populate the Job board with all job entry in the DB but page remains unchanged. The result is the figure above and no error is displayed in console.

Comment: whats in the fetchJobs function?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you expected and what you got, and how you tried to troublshoot it -- "not working" is not a good description

Comment: I have updated the post. I was trying to display the ordered list through fetchJobs (maybe I'm doing wrong)